# Change back button depending on the page content

Tags: javascript, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce with toolset types to create a custom shopping page where the user can select categories and tags etc.  When a user visits the single-product page, I want them to be able to go back to the previous search, not just the starting shop page.  I have created a product page and added a javascript back button "(Continue Shopping)".

```
<button class="continueShoppingBack" type="button" onclick="history.back();">
```

Now.. If I look at the page and click the "Continue Shopping" button, it works perfectly. However if I add an item to the cart, when I click the continue shopping button, it stays on the same page. I need to click the continue shopping button twice to get it to back to the shopping page with the search.

Is there some way, I can code the button that If add to cart has happened go back twice, else go back once?

I would be grateful for the help or advice. Thank you.

Comment: You can call `history.back()` with a numeric value, to tell it how far it should og back in the history. But you have to determine what value to put in there then, and from your description, so far I can’t tell exactly what you are doing. If both situations happen within the same page, then you will need to find a way to determine if it was called for the initial display, or if you are dealing with the situation _after_ a form submit to add the product to the cart.

Comment: (Or you switch to adding products to the cart via AJAX in the background - then you should not have this whole problem to begin with, if I understood your scenario correctly.)

Comment: I guess, when you add item in the cart, your history gets the same url added, that the reason you have to click more than once to go to search page, what do you think? can you monitor page redirection while adding items into the cart?